# Using OpenGL shader programs on the M1mac

Tags: opengl, glsl, apple-m1, glfw, glew

#### What we want to achieve

I would like to use GLSL shader programs on my M1mac.

#### Assumption

I want to use OlenGL shader program in C++ to display a red screen. However, the shader program is not reflected and the screen remains white.

#### Problem/error message being encountered

The shader program is not reflected. Both compile and run successfully. There are no errors or warnings.

#### What we researched and tried

compile command

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lglfw -lglew -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -std=c++11
```

When executed, the shader program is not reflected and a white screen is displayed.

#### Source code in question

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#endif

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Display the compiled result of a shader object
// shader: Shader Object Name
// str: String indicating where the compilation error occurred
GLboolean printShaderInfoLog(GLuint shader, const char *str) {
  // Obtain compilation results
  GLint status;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE) std::cerr << "Compile Error in " << str << std::endl;
  // Get the length of the shader's compile-time log
  GLsizei bufSize;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufSize);
  if (bufSize > 1) {
    // Get the contents of the shader's compile-time log
    std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(bufSize);
    GLsizei length;
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, bufSize, &length, &infoLog[0]);
    std::cerr << &infoLog[0] << std::endl;
  }
  return static_cast<GLboolean>(status);
}

// Display the results of linking program objects
// program: Program Object Name
GLboolean printProgramInfoLog(GLuint program) {
  // Get link results
  GLint status;
  glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
  if (status == GL_FALSE) std::cerr << "Link Error." << std::endl;
  // Get the length of the shader's log at the time of linking
  GLsizei bufSize;
  glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufSize);
  if (bufSize > 1) {
    // Get the contents of the log when linking shaders
    std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(bufSize);
    GLsizei length;
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, bufSize, &length, &infoLog[0]);
    std::cerr << &infoLog[0] << std::endl;
  }
  return static_cast<GLboolean>(status);
}

// Create a program object
// vsrc: Vertex shader source program string
// fsrc: Fragment shader source program string
GLuint createProgram(const char *vsrc, const char *fsrc) {
  // Create an empty program object
  const GLuint program(glCreateProgram());
  if (vsrc != NULL) {
    // Create a shader object for a vertex shader
    const GLuint vobj(glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
    glShaderSource(vobj, 1, &vsrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vobj);
    // Incorporate vertex shader objects into program objects
    if (printShaderInfoLog(vobj, "vertex shader"))
      glAttachShader(program, vobj);
    glDeleteShader(vobj);
  }
  if (fsrc != NULL) {
    // Create a shader object for a fragment shader
    const GLuint fobj(glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
    glShaderSource(fobj, 1, &fsrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fobj);
    // Incorporate shader objects of fragment shaders into program
    // objects
    if (printShaderInfoLog(fobj, "fragment shader"))
      glAttachShader(program, fobj);
    glDeleteShader(fobj);
  }
  // Linking Program Objects
  glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
  glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "fragment");
  glLinkProgram(program);
  // Returns the created program object
  if (printProgramInfoLog(program)) return program;
  // Returns 0 if program object cannot be created
  glDeleteProgram(program);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  // Initialize GLFW
  if (glfwInit() == GL_FALSE) {
    // Initialization failed.
    std::cerr << "Can't initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  // Register processing at the end of the program
  atexit(glfwTerminate);

  // Select OpenGL Version 3.2 Core Profile
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  // Create a window
  GLFWwindow *const window(glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello!", NULL, NULL));
  if (window == NULL) {
    // Window could not be created.
    std::cerr << "Can't create GLFW window." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  // Make the created window an OpenGL target
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  // Initialize GLEW
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    // GLEW initialization failed.
    std::cerr << "Can't initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // Wait for vertical synchronous timing
  glfwSwapInterval(1);

  // Specify background color
  glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

  // Source program for vertex shader
  static constexpr GLchar vsrc[] =
      "#version 150 core\n"
      "in vec4 position;\n"
      "void main()\n"
      "{\n"
      " gl_Position = position;\n"
      "}\n";
  // Fragment shader source program
  static constexpr GLchar fsrc[] =
      "#version 150 core\n"
      "out vec4 fragment;\n"
      "void main()\n"
      "{\n"
      " fragment = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
      "}\n";
  // Create a program object
  const GLuint program(createProgram(vsrc, fsrc));

  // Repeat while window is open
  while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE) {
    // Clear Window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Start using shader program
    glUseProgram(program);
    // replace the color buffer
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    // retrieve an event
    glfwWaitEvents();
  }
}
```

#### Supplementary information (tool version)

PC Environment OS: macOS Monterey version 12.3.1 MacBook Air (M1, 2020) Chip: Apple M1 Memory: 16GB

g++ version
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.3)

compile command

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lglfw -lglew -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -std=c++11
```

Comment: Inbetween `glUseProgram(program);` and `glfwSwapBuffers(window);` you need to actually render something, at least a couple of triangles covering screen. `glUseProgram` does not execute shader, it only reconfigures rendering pipeline.

Comment: @user7860670
```fragment = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);```
Doesn't this program fill the window with red?

Comment: It does not. It is executed for each pixel covered by geometric primitive (such as triangle) on the rendering target. So it won't be executed unless you send some geometry for rendering.

Comment: Please refer to a good teaching resource such as [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/).

Comment: @user7860670
Thank you very much.Add a process to draw the shape after ```glUseProgram(program);``` and you have done it.